# search by JSON values of SQLITE column

Tags: sql, react-native, sqlite

I have a column in an SQLITE table in the format:

```
{
  "position": "3",
  "group": "3015",
  "order": 15
}
```

How can I fetch a row having `position` = `3`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRow(json,completion){
    db.executeSql("SELECT * from positions WHERE position=?", [json.position], (tx, results) => {
       if(tx.rows.length>0){
         let row = tx.rows.item(0);
         completion(row)
       }else{
         completion(null)
       }
     }, (err) => {
    
     })
}
```

Then call it

```
getRow({"position": "3","group": "3015","order": 15},(row)=>{
   console.log("Row from db")
})
```

Cheers.